# Call I call a function to self reset?

Tags: c, process

Let's say I get myself into a situation where I do not know how to recover. What would be the best way to self restart the process? What I'm looking for is something similar to closing itself and launching itself again. On some arduino's I can call NVIC_SystemReset however I'd like a function for windows, mac and linux.

I was thinking perhaps the only way is to execute a detached process and let myself shut down? With shellexecute on windows and execl on linux?

Comment: You can't compare error handling on a microcontroller system with error handling of desktop PCs. There is no watchdog, there is no power-on reset. In case of hardware faults, the PC will at best reboot, at worst roll over and die. Most hardware error handling is handled by the OS and/or drivers.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Lundin, this is for processor not micro-controller.

This answer might not be correct in your case.

1) Create a proxy process to delegate to main process.

2) This proxy process will redirect to main process.

3) If your main process fails/return due to any reason then restart the main process. Otherwise if it normal exit of main program then end the proxy process.